# Ubuntu 10.10 network connection cut down after few minutes of starting

Tags: ubuntu, networking, cut

Ubuntu 10.10 network connection works fine at the start, but few minutes later the network manager pops up a message saying `disconnected you are offline` and Chrome browser returns an error message like `name not resolved`.

This works fine in Windows 7. It was fine too in Ubuntu, until I updated it with 300 MB worth of updates.

Comment: i'm using windows 7 now and this was happening in WiFi and Ethernet  to reconnect i had to restart and enjoy 5 minutes of internet then disconnected and you are offline

Comment: It's hard to parse your English, and you mentioning Windows makes it look like the problem is there as well. So, please split your sentences with commas `,` and periods `.` next time.

Comment: Try to reproduce, and when it happens again, paste here the last several lines of `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: If it's happening on both Windows and Ubuntu, it's probably a problem with your network equipment (router) or with your Internet provider.

Answer (score 1):

to work on Ubuntu, I would inspect the 300 MB uploads, what could be the cause, where a new kernel would be most suspicious.

If you still have the old kernel laying around and configured in grub, I would try to use these older kernels.

In synaptic, there is a history in the file menu. There you can probably reconstruct what was actualized when, together with the date of your posting.

```
ls -l /boot/vml*
```

will show you the age of kernels.